# Very ample + effective = ample?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, birational-geometry

It is well known that there exist divisors (on a normal projective variety over say the complex numbers) that are big (= is a sum of an ample and an effective divisor) but not ample. However, if we strengthen ample to very ample, does the statement hold true?

Comment: See the linked duplicate for an instance of a very ample divisor which when added to an effective divisor does not give a very ample divisor.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've changed the question slightly, haven't found an answer.

Comment: [Now asked and answered on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460766/very-ample-effective-ample).